# Build existing autoconf C project to include in smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, c++, dapp-development

I'd like to include [GNU's GMP](https://gmplib.org) library in my smart contract project.

It's an `autotools/autoconf` project, how can I compile it as a standalone webassembly library and then include it in my smart contract compilation?

Could I use this [fork](https://github.com/torquem-ch/gmp-wasm)? Seems it uses the [WASI SDK](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk)

Comment: This is a question for the real horsepower: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1.  This is the EOSIO Developer Telegram channel where some of the creators and the community answer questions. Welcome to EOSIO.